# Unity set RectTransform width independent from height

Tags: unity, c#

The usual way to set the width or height for a `RectTransform` is this one as far as I know : `RectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(...);` . I want to set the width of my object in an EditorScript, so if I would use the mentioned method, I would automatically lock my height value in the editor. But I want to freely adjust my height and at the same time let the width be calculated from my script. So my problem is, that `RectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(...);` is locking both values in the Editor.

Comment: Why not `RectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(calculatedWidth, RectRansform.sizeDelta.y)`?

Comment: That's all the question is about, your line of code would lock the height in my editor, but I still want to adjust it.

Comment: Tried it like this: http://pastebin.com/Rpeu3YmJ Don't see any height locking.

Comment: Well shame on me for not trying your line of code... I did it like this : RectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(calculatedWidth, RectRansform.rect.height); And that locked the height so I thought everything would do that... Thanks a lot! I would like to accept this as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read current height and set it again without changing. When you change height in the editor, it'll be changed between your code executions.

```
RectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(calculatedWidth, RectRansform.sizeDelta.y)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common problem, actually. Unity provides [`SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors.html) for setting either width or height, ignoring the current anchors (which is almost certainly what you want).